# Weird looking menu (bootstrap nav-pills)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this weird looking pills as the screenshot shows:
[image]

Below is my code for the nav-pills

```html
<div class = "container-fluid">
  <ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li><a href="admin_home.php">Home</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="account.php">Account</a></li>
    <li><a href="auditee_u.php">Auditee</a></li>
    <li><a href="auditor.php">Auditor</a></li>
    <li><a href="standard.php">Standard</li>
    <li><a href="clause.php">Clause</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I cant find any error in the code. or am i missing something here?
Thanks for your help

Comment: Welcome! Please include at least the relevant CSS in the code snippet, describe exactly in which way your code does not behave as you expected and tell us what you have done so far to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think something missing after your pills code, Can you please provide full code in container-fluid div?

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class = "container-fluid">
  <ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li><a href="admin_home.php">Home</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="account.php">Account</a></li>
    <li><a href="auditee_u.php">Auditee</a></li>
    <li><a href="auditor.php">Auditor</a></li>
    <li><a href="standard.php">Standard</a></li>
    <li><a href="clause.php">Clause</a></li>
  </ul>
  
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks. i dont even realize that i miss </a> there. what a stupid mistake. haha

Comment: Zulfahmi Radzi, this answer doesn't say anything about the closing tags, please mark the other answer as correct (which does point out the issue).

What happened was that someone edited your post to include the missing tags so that confused people

Answer (score 0):

Bacause you may didn't close your `<A>` tags. Check the snippet below for the correct html.

```html
<div class = "container-fluid">
  <ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li><a href="admin_home.php">Home</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="account.php">Account</a></li>
    <li><a href="auditee_u.php">Auditee</a></li>
    <li><a href="auditor.php">Auditor</a></li>
    <li><a href="standard.php">Standard</a></li>
    <li><a href="clause.php">Clause</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Next time, don't edit the question, because that makes it make no sense.